# Set querystring when creating new instance of a page in code behind

Tags: c#, silverlight, .net-4.0

In a Silverlight application page I've created a new instance of another page.

```
MyPage2 Pippo = new MyPage2();
```

In the `MyPage2` `OnNavigatedTo` event I do some stuff depending on the query string.

How can I pass a query string when creating a page like before?

Thanks in advance,

Bye ;)

Comment: I saw that the event 'OnNavigatedTo' also doesn't get fired. Any suggestion for set the correct querystring and load the page in the variable `Pippo` like it is navigated by the user but without showing anything? 
All this stuff is because i need to take some data from the page `MyPage2`, but this data are available only after the page is full loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is based on "bad" design... I do not know what you want to do but if there is anything that gets calculated or loaded from wherever on your "MyPage2", why dont you exctract this code and use it wherever you need this information?

Comment: Sure it's a "bad design" problem! Unfortunately this application was written mainly by another developer (which is now gone from my company) and this is the first time I work on it. The problem of extracting code is that I have a lot of pages (about 50) and I hope to not touch that code. :(

Comment: Feeling with you... Have you tried to fire the navigation events yourself(parsing arguments as needed) and try to get the informations afterwards? Anyway would I refactor this page(s)...